# use comparison test to show divergence or convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct.

a) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)+10\sin(n)}}{n\cdot \ln^6{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)\cdot\ln{\ln{(n+(-1)^n}})} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n $

here I think it suffice to show that for big enough $n$ we have all logs $>1$ and $\sin n \ge -1$ so we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{-9}{n} \le a_n $ so $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges.

b) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{n^2+3n+10}{n^2+5n+17})^{n^2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})}= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} b_n$

we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} b_n= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(1-\frac{2n+7}{n^2+5n+17})^{\frac{2n^2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}}}$ and here I don't know how to compare it

Comment: $\sin n$ is not a monotonic function so you cannot compare it that way. In fact it gets arbitrarily close to 0 for integers near large multiples of 3pi/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part (b):**

The exponent of $b_n$ satisfies

$$\frac{2n^2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}}< \frac{2n^2}{\sqrt{n+1}}< 2n\sqrt{n}.$$

For sufficiently large $n$

$$1-\frac{2n+7}{n^2+5n+17}= 1-\frac{2}{n}\frac{1+7/(2n)}{1+5/n+17/n^2}< 1 - \frac{1}{n},$$

using

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+7/(2n)}{1+5/n+17/n^2} = 1 \implies\frac{1+7/(2n)}{1+5/n+17/n^2} > \frac1{2}.$$

Using the inequality $\displaystyle (1+x/n)^{n+1}> e^x,$ we have

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^n= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{-n}<e^{-1}.$$

Hence, for sufficiently large n,

$$b_n < \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n\sqrt{n}}< e^{-2\sqrt{n}}.$$

Note that $e^n$ grows faster than any power of $n$.  We easily can find a dominating convergent p-series.

$$e^{2\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\sqrt{n})^k}{k!}> \frac{(2\sqrt{n})^4}{4!}=\frac{2n^2}{3}\\ \implies e^{-2\sqrt{n}} < \frac{3}{2}n^{-2}.$$

Therefore, by the comparison test

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} b_n < \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} e^{-2\sqrt{n}}< \frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^{-2} = \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\right).$$

**Part (a):**

Note that for sufficiently large $n$

$$\frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)+10\sin(n)}}{\ln^5{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)} > \frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)-10}}{\ln^5{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)} > 1.$$

Also

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n^{\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)}{n} = 0, \\ n+ (-1)^n \leqslant n+1,$$

and for sufficiently large $n$ we have

$$ \ln(n^{\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1) < \ln n, \\ \ln \ln (n+ (-1)^n) \leqslant \ln \ln (n+1),$$

Thus,

$$a_n = \frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)+10\sin(n)}}{n\cdot \ln^6{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)\cdot\ln{\ln{(n+(-1)^n}})} > \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln n \cdot \ln \ln (n+1)} \\ > \frac{1}{(n+1) \cdot \ln (n+1) \cdot \ln \ln (n+1)} .$$

The series with terms given by the RS of the above inequality diverges by the integral test, since

$$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1) \cdot \ln (x+1) \cdot \ln \ln (x+1) }= \lim_{x \to \infty}[\ln \ln \ln(x+1)- \ln \ln \ln (3)] = \infty.$$

Comment: ok but how to show that $e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent ?

Comment: @Thomas:  $e^x$ grows faster than any power of $x$.  So $e^{-\sqrt{n}} < Cn^{-2}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: ok thank you, do you know if i did a) correctly ?

Comment: Yes -- $\sin(n) \geqslant -1$ for all $n$ so you can drop that term for a lower bound. Let me look at the rest.

Comment: @ RRL sorry for trouble but I don't know how to compare the very last term by some diverging series

Comment: Its not divergent - so its the wrong approach, Ill try to fix it.

Comment: No wolfram says the $a_n$ series is divergent

Comment: Yes - I fixed the proof with a better lower bound, for which the series diverges.